# php code for displaying one account from relational table

Tags: php

this code is running and displaying the relational table.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT member.*, account.*
    FROM member, account
    WHERE member.mem_id = account.mem_id';

mysql_select_db('databasename');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ); 
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "Account Number:{$row['Account_Number']}  <br> ".
     "First Name: {$row['fname']} <br> ".
     "Last Name: {$row['lname']} <br> ".
     "Address: {$row['address']} <br> ".
     "Contact: {$row['contact']} <br> ".
     "Share Capital: {$row['Share_Capital']} <br> ".
     "Regular Savings: {$row['Regular_Savings']} <br> ".
     "Power Savings: {$row['Power_Savings']} <br> ".
     "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Now this is the oputput.

Account Number:
First Name:
Last Name:
Address: 
Contact: 
Share Capital: 
Regular Savings:

### Power Savings:

Account Number:
First Name: 
Last Name: 
Address: 
Contact: 
Share Capital: 
Regular Savings:

### Power Savings:

Fetched data successfully

Now I want to display only one account from the two relational table. For example if I inquire my account number and enter it only the details of my account will be shown not every members. So in my output the whole members and its details inside the database display. How can I manage to displaye only one account from two relational tables.

Comment: This is very basic SQL knowledge, can't you use google?

Comment: already search but google display code for relational tables not a particular one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can extend your where condition like this, i have given $memid = 1 as example, you can pass $memid as POST or GET or any other value to it

```
$memid = 1; // example
$sql = "SELECT member.*, account.* FROM member, account WHERE member.mem_id = account.mem_id AND member.mem_id = '".$memid."' ";
```

may this will help you

Comment: yes, it works I used $memid = 1 it display my first account which have the value of 1. so how about the other account? How will $memid GET value.

Comment: $memid will by any GET or POST value like $memid = $_GET['memid']; or $memid = $_POST['memid'];

Comment: using GET or POST value like $memid = $_GET['memid']; or $memid = $_POST['memid']; display only the "Fetched data successfully" seems their is something wrong.?

Comment: According to your requirement you should have 2 pages, first which will show member list and second one will show member details. Now to link this 2 pages use GET method i.e. on first page give anchor link with name=value pair of "memid" as query string parameter, then on second page you can use above query to show details. Refer this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp. and for post method http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the SQL to filter by the account number you want to query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT member.*, account.*
FROM member, account
WHERE member.mem_id = account.mem_id WHERE account.mem_id = '.intval($_GET['mem_id');
```

Note: this is just any quick example, you might want a better way to build the sql statement

Comment: so my SQL will be $sql = 'SELECT member.*, account.*
FROM member, account
WHERE account.mem_id = '.intval($_GET['mem_id']);?

Comment: Yes, if you pass the member id to the page url like  http://yourdomain.com/yourpage?mem_id=123   The intval() call is a cheap way to avoid SQL injection hack.